# How to get Exception Detail in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I want to get details of Exception in Python3

for example... in foo.py

```
import sys

try:
  {}.encode('utf8')
except:
  err = sys.exc_info()[0]

  print("itself\t", err)
  print(".args\t", err.args)

  print("dir\t", dir(err.args))
  print("type\t", type(err.args))

  print("vars\t", vars(err))

  print("--------k,v in vars---------")
  for k,v in vars(err).items():
    print(k)
    print(v)
```

and stdout is...

```
itself   <class 'AttributeError'>
.args    <attribute 'args' of 'BaseException' objects>
dir      ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__delete__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__objclass__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__set__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
type     <class 'getset_descriptor'>
vars     {'__init__': <slot wrapper '__init__' of 'AttributeError' objects>, '__doc__': 'Attribute not found.', '__new__': <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x821c3a0>}
--------k,v in vars---------
__init__
<slot wrapper '__init__' of 'AttributeError' objects>
__doc__
Attribute not found.
__new__
<built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x821c3a0>
```

I want more information of this built in Exception class from instance "err",

such as

- FILE : foo.py
- LINE : 4
- MESSAGE : 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'

just like stdout of this code

```
{}.encode('utf8')
```

this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "foo.py", line 2, in <module>

    {}.encode('utf8')

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`traceback` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) to print tracebacks from your current position or for a given exception.

You don't state what output you are expecting, but the `traceback` module most likely will be able to produce output best suited for your needs, whatever they may be.

Comment: Exactly that's what I want!! Thank you very much! and I will study about traceback module more.