# How to customize exception message

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# python 3.5
>>> class MyError(Exception):
...   pass
...
>>> raise MyError('message')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
__main__.MyError: message
```

I want the exception to print just `message` instead of `__main__.MyError: message`. I tried defininig `__str__` and `__repr__` in both `MyError` itself and in its metaclass, but those had no effect. Where does python interpreter get `__main__.MyError` from?

Note that I can easily change how instances of `MyError` are printed, and how `MyError` itself is printed, but neither has any effect on the exception message:

```
class MyType(type):
  def __str__(self):
    return '***'

class MyError(Exception, metaclass=MyType):
  def __str__(self):
    return 'xxx'

print(MyError) # ***
print(MyError()) # xxx
raise MyError() # still the same
```

Comment: And you don't want to catch and print the message?

Comment: `__main__.MyError` is the object you raised as an exception.

Comment: @AChampion Yes of course, but I usually can customize the string representation of the object. Not so in this case.

Comment: @yBot Yes of couse, but I'm trying to understand how exception reporting works.

Comment: You can customize the `__str__()` and `__repr__()` but you will need to redefine `sys.excepthook()` if you want to customize how the interpreter prints out an unhandled exception. You could of course just handle it.

Comment: @AChampion but where does `sys.excepthook()` take this weird `__main__.MyError` from if not from `type(MyError).__str__` and not from `MyError.__str__`?

Comment: In `ipython` I just get `__main__.MyError` for `my_error.__class__` but in the standard interpreter I get `<class '__main__.MyError'>

Comment: @AChampion `my_error.__class__` prints out the value of `str(MyError)`, which can be overridden by `type(MyError).__str__` as in my code. That doesn't seem to be what `excepthook` uses.

Comment: Not really `my_error.__class__` uses `sys.displayhook` to print out the value, and this must be different between python and ipython. In ipython `str(my_error.__class__`) is `<class 'main.MyError'>`

Comment: @AChampion ah yes you're right! didn't know about `sys.displayhook`. But still, I'm using a regular interpreter, its `sys.displayhook` is the original one (which prints classes as `<class '__main__.MyError'>`), and yet exceptions are shown with just `__main__.MyError`.

Comment: @AChampion I know.. at the end of the exception report, `sys.displayhook` just does something like `print(value.__class__.__module__  + '.' + value.__class__.__name__ + ':', value, file=sys.stderr)`, where `value` is the exception object it received as an argument. It completely ignores any `__str__` methods. Can you post your comments as an answer?

Comment: Try using the `traceback` module (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17859166/2531279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing I could get is this:

```
In [6]: raise MyError("some message")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MyError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4bd48c5b1ce0> in <module>()
----> 1 raise MyError("some error message")

MyError: some error message
```

There is a way to remove leading `__main__.` text in front of class name. There is even a way to remove class name itself, so output looks like this:

```
In [6]: raise MyError("some error message")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-4bd48c5b1ce0> in <module>()
----> 1 raise MyError("some error message")

: some error message
```

However, I couldn't find a way to remove `:` sign. My guess is that this sign is generated by interpreter in order to clearly separate exception output from other output types.

Here's the solution I used:

```
class MyError(Exception):
    __module__ = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Exception.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__class__.__name__ = "CustomTextHere"
```

And some outputs:

```
In [8]: MyError
Out[8]: MyError

In [9]: MyError()
Out[9]: None.CustomTextHere()

In [11]: raise MyError()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CustomTextHere                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f389ee70e588> in <module>()
----> 1 raise MyError()

CustomTextHere: 

In [12]: raise MyError("some error message")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CustomTextHere                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-4bd48c5b1ce0> in <module>()
----> 1 raise MyError("some error message")

CustomTextHere: some error message
```

If You want to get only `:` sign, you would use:

```
self.__class__.__name__ = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

The first part of that line, before the colon, is the *type* of the Exception raised.  It's in the same format as what's returned by:

```
>>> class MyError(Exception):
...     pass
...
>>> print(type(MyError("message")))
<class '__main__.MyError'>
```

Usually your custom exception class will be put inside some file (say, file.py), and imported, so in that case, it would be `file.MyError` isntead of `__main__.MyError`.  However, since you're currently using an Exception defined in the main python file, the only namespace it has to use is `__main__`.

Long story short, if you want it to be prettier, put it in another file with the name you'd like.

Comment: `<class '__main__.MyError'>` is the string representation of `MyError` class. I can customize it easily by defining `__str__` in the metaclass of `MyError`. But as I said, I could not change what python exception report shows. Also note that `__main__.MyError` is _not_ the same as `<class '__main__.MyError'>`.

Comment: So I did some digging in the Python source code, and it appears the way that string is determined is <module name>.<class name>; you can easily change the class name by renaming your class, or dynamically modifying MyError.__name__.  However, I don't believe there is a way to dynamically change the module name, as this is determined in the C source (Link at the end of comment), based on what file is being executed. I'm not entirely clear on how this works, though, so it could be possible. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pythonrun.c#L756

Comment: Yup, you're right. Can you add this to your answer?

Comment: I think I'll leave it out, since the other answer seems to solve the problem much better! I basically said I don't know if this can be done, and they showed that it could.